# Why won't this JOGL program run?

Tags: java, eclipse, javadoc, jogl

I am using Eclipse, i have no errors until i actually run it, when i run it i get a JVM Error and i have no idea what it means. Here is the error.:

```
#
# A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:
#
#  Internal Error (classFileParser.cpp:3174), pid=20996, tid=20564
#  Error: ShouldNotReachHere()
#
# JRE version: 6.0_20-b02
# Java VM: Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (16.3-b01 mixed mode windows-amd64 )
# An error report file with more information is saved as:
# C:\xampp\htdocs\android\FireRunn\hs_err_pid20996.log
#
# If you would like to submit a bug report, please visit:
#   http://java.sun.com/webapps/bugreport/crash.jsp
#
```

And this is the actual code which is supposed to simply open a frame in Eclipse, but it doesn't. Whats Wrong?  And what is the role of a Javadoc? because in the Javadoc side of eclipse i get "Note: This element neither has attached source nor attached Javadoc and hence no Javadoc could be found."

```
import javax.media.opengl.*;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Frame;
import java.awt.event.WindowAdapter;
import java.awt.event.WindowEvent;
import javax.media.opengl.GLCapabilities;
public class Forest{//open forest



    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Frame frame = new Frame("Hello World");

        GLCapabilities glcapabilities = new GLCapabilities();
        GLCanvas glcanvas = new GLCanvas(glcapabilities);
        frame.add(glcanvas);

        frame.setSize(300, 300);
        frame.setBackground(Color.WHITE);

        frame.addWindowListener(new WindowAdapter() {

            public void windowClosing(WindowEvent e) {
                System.exit(0);
            }
        });//close forest
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

Comment: The javadoc of a class (=> a library) is a documentation generated from the class /** comments */ (Note the double asterisk on the beginning). If you bind a library to its javadoc under Eclipse, it will be able to show it in the Javadoc view

Answer (score 1):

For starters, you are using jogl1 which is not maintained anymore. You should be using jogl2 from jogamp.org. Then you should port your code to jogl2. That should fix it.